# Computer's turn on/off (hibernate/wake up) time

Tags: c#, windows

Is there an universal way (working on Windows XP/Vista/7) to determine the time of 'turn off/turn on' or 'hibernate/wake up' of the computer?

edit: I want to determine it programmatically.

Comment: Do you mean when it happened, or how long the timeout is before it happens automatically? Or something else? The question isn't clear.

Comment: Check the event viewer.  Start -> Run -> eventvwr.exe

Comment: @Joe White: when it happened

Comment: I just need to grab the last wake up time of a computer programmatically (C#) and can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) class.

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding your answer to make it self-contained.  External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  It's better to include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to access the BIOS if the system in question is using any Wake-On-LAN settings.  You would use the Win32_BIOS class for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a setting in Windows, check out the WMI classes in .Net (System.Management namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Initializes a new instance of the [ManagementClass class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wzwcace.aspx). The class represents a Common Information Model (CIM) management class from WMI [Classes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394362%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Check example on the documentation [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wzwcace.aspx) that may help you about usage of these.

For more information, see "Win32 Classes" in the Windows Management Instrumentation documentation in the MSDN Library [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394362%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

If you use Windows Development Kit library then there are lots of library methods to get information either using WMI classes and scripting management catalogs.

If you get it through windows development kit then check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394362%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/31/get-windows-power-plan-settings-on-your-computer-by-using-powershell.aspx